# mysql smart replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Is it possible to setup some kind of smart replication, so that these columns are automatically updated if they are changed in another database ..

Like : rows are automatiically added, some columns are automatically synced, but other columns are not

Comment: Let's say you have a four-column table. You want (for example) to sync only two of them. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to perform an action on the same database server rather than a remote DB? If so, the device you want are triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html